C and getchar() behaviour
I am pretty new to coding and I read the K&R book. As I try to solve proposed exercises, I face my first problem (1-13).
Why with, the code below I get tabul populated
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == ' ' || c =='\n' || c == '\t') {
        ++tabul[lw];
        lw = 0;
    } 
    else
        ++lw;
}

and not with
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c != ' ' || c !='\n' || c != '\t') {
        ++lw;
    } else {
        ++tabul[lw];
        lw = 0;
    }
}

?

In the second code you want the if statement to succeed when c is not equal to ' ' AND not equal to '\n' AND not equal to '\t', so the condition is wrong, because you are using the OR (||) operator instead of AND (&&).

Think about it: if (it's Saturday || it's Sunday) /* on weekend */; versus if (it's not Saturday || it's not Sunday) /* everyday */;

It's not even a programming problem. Some basic discreet math/boolean algebra is recommended prerequisite knowledge before picking up any form of programming, C and low-level programming in particular.

To invert a logical OR, you need to (1) invert the individual terms and (2) change the OR to AND.  This is an application of De Morgan's laws.  So what you want is:
if (c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '\t') {

The original version with || will always be true, since c can equal at most one of those characters.

c != ' ' || c != '\n' || c != '\t'

Is not the inverse of:
c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t'

You're wanting && to check that all of those conditions are true, rather than any of them being true. When checking if any of them are true, the result will always be true. If c is a space, then it must not be a tab.
c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '\t'

Alternatively, you may wish to include <ctype.h> and use isspace to test this.
Even more alternatively, we can try to find the current character in a string composed of the whitespace characters with strchr. This would allow us to easily add other characters (including non-whitespace characters) to our check.
char *spaces = " \t\n";

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (strchr(spaces, c)) {
        ++tabul[lw];
        lw = 0;
    } 
    else {
        ++lw;
    }
}


In your second example c != ' ' || c != '\n' || c != '\t' will always be true.
No matter what character you put in c, it will either be not equal to ' ' or not equal to '\n' (and the check will never get further than that due to short-circuiting).
You want logical and instead:
c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '\t'

Reading it out-loud may help:
If c is not equal to space and c is not equal to newline and c is not equal to tab then ...
